# Binding label inside a gridview from codebehind.

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to bind my totalcomplete variable to lblComplete that is in my gridProgress but i don't know how to do it, can anybody help me out?

ASP Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridProgress" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete">
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
          <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblComplete" runat="server"></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Code:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, oConn);
da.Fill(ds);


//count number of tasks completed, not completed
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
string value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Completed"].ToString();
int completed = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   if (value == "No")
   {
       completed++;
   }                
   int totalcomplete = completed;
   //here i want to bind totalcomplete to my lblCompleted
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `FindControl` property of `Gridview`.

```
Label lbl = gv.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lblComplete") as Label;
lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(totalcomplete);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.
Do you want to display the totlalComplete in each row
Or somewhere else?

As you have a template field inside gridview
So it is going to render in every row

**And your loop too is strange**
It should be as follow

```
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
int completed = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   string value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Completed"].ToString();
   if (value == "No")
   {
      completed++;
   }                
   int totalcomplete = completed;
   //here i want to bind totalcomplete to my lblCompleted
}
```

### Edit 1

Here is a link which may help you
[Displaying Total in Footer of GridView and also Add Sum of columns(row vise) in last Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734308/displaying-total-in-footer-of-gridview-and-also-add-sum-of-columnsrow-vise-in) 

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-total-in-gridview-footer.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `DataBinder.Eval method`

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"totalcomplete") %>'
```