# how to sum the column which is in the dataset and display in the footer

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            int IndexTypeID = 5;
            mobjORACLE = new DatabaseObjects.OracleDBCalls();
            DataSet dsetPortfolio = mobjORACLE.GetORACLEDataSet(IndexTypeID, "v_indextypeid", "cv_1", "fn_getportfolio");

            if (dsetPortfolio.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ViewState["gvPortfolio_DataSource"] = dsetPortfolio.Tables[0];
                gvPortfolio.DataSource = dsetPortfolio.Tables[0];
                gvPortfolio.DataBind();
                gvPortfolio.Visible = true;
                //dsetPortfolio.Tables[0].Rows[0]["cashreserve"];

                //ViewState["gvPortfolio_DataSource"] = gvPortfolio.DataSource;
                gvPortfolio.Attributes.Add("bordercolor", "#999966");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

In gvPortfolio i got a datatable which has a column by name amount allocated. Now the question is, i need to sum up the column and display its result in the footer. Can somebody help me out in getting out of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Total in Footer of GridView and also Add Sum of columns(row vise) in last Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734308/displaying-total-in-footer-of-gridview-and-also-add-sum-of-columnsrow-vise-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).

Excerpt from Microsoft Documentation:

> Before the GridView control can be rendered, each row in the control
>   must be bound to a record in the data source. The RowDataBound event
>   is raised when a data row (represented by a GridViewRow object) is
>   bound to data in the GridView control. This enables you to provide an
>   event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as
>   modifying the values of the data bound to the row, whenever this event
>   occurs.

For example:

```
void gvPortfolio_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        // Once you know you are in the footer row
        // the sender object is the GridView and you can get the datasource
        // loop thru the datatable adding up the values you want
        // For example: let say column 3 have the number
        // **** code is not tested - writing from memory ***
        int total = 0;
        int column = 3;
        foreach(DataRow row in (DataTable)(sender.DataSource).Rows)
        {
              if (!row.IsNull(column))
              {
                  // probably need more checking to make sure we have a valid integer
                  total += Convert.ToInt32(row[column]);
              }
        }

        e.Row.Cells[column].Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This look cool. But can you help me out with datagrid instead of gridview. I am unable to locate a event that matches with this. Please help me out using the datagrid :)

Comment: @Krish - For `DataGrid` it's the [DataGrid.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx). The [DataGridItem.ItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagriditem.itemtype.aspx) will tell you if it's a `Footer`.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning I believe that this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734308/displaying-total-in-footer-of-gridview-and-also-add-sum-of-columnsrow-vise-in) should help you with what you are trying to accomplish.