# Add GridView Column grand total to label

Tags: c#, asp.net

HI i am trying to add the numbers of a row into a label outside of the gridview.  How would I do this??

Here is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="539px" BackColor="White"  BorderColor="#DEDFDE"  BorderStyle="Double" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" BorderWidth="1px"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"  CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Font-Size="Small"  >
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ShowHeader="False">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Height="22px" ImageUrl="~/images/dialog-close.png" onclientclick=" return confirm('Are you want to Delete this Item?');" Text="Delete" Width="22px" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>

<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>

                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here are the Gridview Rows:

```
                dr["PartNumber"] = dtparts.Rows[i]["PartNumber"];
                dr["Qty"] = qty;
                dr["Price"] = priceff;
                dr["ExtPrice"] = "$" + Convert.ToDouble(qty) * Convert.ToDouble(pricedb);

                dttemp.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the totals in the RowDataBound event.  Then, take that sum and assign it to your label.  It looks like there are a few examples of this..[here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734308/displaying-total-in-footer-of-gridview-and-also-add-sum-of-columnsrow-vise-in?rq=1).