# Programmatically Add Values To Grid View Footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, footer

I have a grid view that displays values, I need to sum some of the values and display the sums in the footer.  How can I control which column the sums display in?

Lets say for example if my grid view looks like this:

> ID --- Name --- Store # --- # of Sales 
>   
> 1      Bob               123                  14
>   
> 2         Joe                456              21 
>   
> 3          Mike             818                  10

So obviously I want my Total Sales Header to Display in

```
gvwSales.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = "Total Sales";
gvwSales.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text = SUM(#ofSales);
```

But this logic does not add the info to my footer.  How do I use this logic (or any other logic) to control the position that data is added to a grid view footer?

**EDIT**
My ? is different than the suggested duplicate as they want to add the Sum in the last column, I want to add the sum in the footer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Total in Footer of GridView and also Add Sum of columns(row vise) in last Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734308/displaying-total-in-footer-of-gridview-and-also-add-sum-of-columnsrow-vise-in)

Comment: @SteveWellens - I could be missing it but that shows how to set the footer text programmatically.  I need to know how to add the sum of columns to a specific footer column programmatically.

Comment: The footer doesn't have columns.

Comment: @SteveWellens - my ? is different from your suggested duplicate as I awnt to add the sumsin the footer, not in the last column.

Comment: The example is putting the sum in the footer.  Since a footer has no columns, he/she has put a label control in the footer and is putting the sum there.

Comment: @SteveWellens - how do I put the sum under my 4th column?  I would like my footer to show under the ID Column to Show the text "Totals" and under the 4th column show the sum.  How can I control the position they display in the footer?

Comment: Google:  Add label to gridview footer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I finally did it.  I can provide further syntax if need be, but I think this will show how I achieved this.

```
protected void gvwSales_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        decimal tmptotalsales = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "totalsales").ToString());
        GrandTotalSales += tmptotalsales; 
    }      
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;
        e.Row.Cells[3].Font.Bold = true;
        e.Row.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        e.Row.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Total Sales";
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = GrandTotalSales.ToString("F");
    }
}
```