# Calculate total price in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm new to ASP.NET. I have a situation like below:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookID" HeaderText="Book ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookName" HeaderText="Book Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Testing Field">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenPrice" Value='<%#Eval("Price") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="ddlQuantity" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Total" Enabled="false" Text="asdfsdf" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

As you can see I have a dropdownlist inside a gridview. Every time I choose a different number in the list, it calculates the price and add to the `Total` Textbox (Price*Number).

So my question is how can I calculate the total price of all `Total` textbox and output the result to the label outside girdview?

Here is my code behind file:

```
private static OBMDbContext context = new OBMDbContext();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = context.Books.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void ddlQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt16(ddl.SelectedItem.Value);
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)ddl.FindControl("Total");
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)ddl.FindControl("HiddenPrice");
    tb.Text = (quantity * Convert.ToInt16(hf.Value)).ToString();
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Refer to the Microsoft tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310552.aspx

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @AlexBell ,  you're the best :)

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: @vuhiep.tran: Have already answered similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734308/displaying-total-in-footer-of-gridview-and-also-add-sum-of-columnsrow-vise-in/11734507#11734507

Answer (score 0):

Is the textbox is outside the gridview, you won't be having a problem reaching it.

If you can't, you may try reaching it by:

```
 (DropDownList)sender.Parent
```

@Alex Bell s link is also a better solution:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310552.aspx