# Insert Header Between rows If name Is Different in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I Have a gridview and I want to show Header/Space with the column having heading "AccountManager"(Column 1) as name between rows.  If Name Is Different and sum of columns "Mins" , "Amount" , and "Profit" of per accountmanager in the space/Header above every "AccountManager".

This is my GridView(HTML):

```
<asp:gridview runat="server" id="GridView2" showfooter="true" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false" GridLines="None" CssClass="table" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" RowStyle-CssClass="td" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" onrowcreated="GridView2_RowCreated">
    <columns>

        <asp:boundfield datafield="Date" headertext="Date" 
            footerstyle-font-bold="true"  >
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="AccountManager" headertext="AccountManager" 
            footerstyle-font-bold="true"  >
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>

         <asp:boundfield datafield="" headertext="Total" footerstyle-font-bold="true" 
            footertext="Grand Total:" >
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="MIns" headertext="Mins" 
            footerstyle-font-bold="true"   >
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Amount" headertext="Amount" footerstyle-font-bold="true" 
             >
 <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>

        <asp:boundfield datafield="Profit" headertext="Profit"  
            footerstyle-font-bold="true">
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>

   </columns>

 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CEFF99" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="#C1FF80" BorderStyle="Solid" 
              BorderWidth="1px"></HeaderStyle>

<RowStyle CssClass="td"></RowStyle>
</asp:gridview>
```

Kindly help...i m in soooooo trouble.

Comment: Are you saying you want the account manager name to show once, and be blank for the rest of the entries until it changes?

Comment: yes...exactly...in the header i want to show account manager name for once only until it changes...and the sum of the his "mins" , "amount" and "profit" where it ends

Answer (score 0):

To sum the values in the footer, You can use this technique:

[Displaying Total in Footer of GridView and also Add Sum of columns(row vise) in last Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734308/displaying-total-in-footer-of-gridview-and-also-add-sum-of-columnsrow-vise-in) .

To not show repeating columns, something like this ([taken from Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25136887/Hide-duplicate-field-values-in-a-GridView.html)):

```
Protected Sub ResultGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles ResultGridView.RowDataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            'switch for first row 
            For j As Integer = 0 To 4
                If e.Row.RowIndex = 1 Then
                    Dim Gprev As GridViewRow = ResultGridView.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex - 1)

                    If Gprev.Cells(j).Text.Equals(e.Row.Cells(j).Text) Then
                        e.Row.Cells(j).Text = ""
                    End If
                End If

                'now continue with the rest of the rows 
                If e.Row.RowIndex > 1 Then
                    'set reference to the row index and the current value 
                    Dim intC As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex
                    Dim lookfor As String = e.Row.Cells(j).Text

                    'now loop back through checking previous entries for matches 
                    Do
                        Dim Gprev As GridViewRow = ResultGridView.Rows(intC - 1)

                        If Gprev.Cells(j).Text.Equals(e.Row.Cells(j).Text) Then
                            e.Row.Cells(j).Text = ""
                        End If

                        intC = intC - 1
                    Loop While intC > 0

                End If
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Brother ...i don't want sum in the footer but in the dynamic row created after  and for every account manger individually...and that too in c#

Comment: The GridView control is just not built to provide grouped data structure like you are referring to.  You may be able to use nested data controls like this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/nested-data-web-controls-cs